# How drastic the performance of a modern computer can change if it operates without cache memory?

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture

Assume a hypothetical modern computer without cache memory. I am wondering ,whether the performance can reduce so drastically that such a system won't be useful for any practical purposes.

Comment: I think you can disable caching on your desktop and see how badly it sucks.  (e.g. modify a Linux kernel to use uncacheable pages instead of write-back for normal memory.  Modern x86 has per-page memory types) 
 If it disables store-forwarding too, it would be extremely slow.  (Many store/reloads are reloaded before the data is even committed to L1d cache, e.g. for passing args on the stack.)

Answer (score 0):

My first google result says "fast RAM chips have an access time of 70ns or less". That's about 200 processor cycles on a modern computer. What's really bad is that because of your lack of instruction cache, each instruction takes 200 cycles to read. And I assume you don't have cached page tables, so every memory access in your program will take several memory access.

It looks pretty bad, but you could always use such a system as a door stop.

Comment: Technically, absence of cache does not exclude on-chip memory. The programming model would be very different (e.g., explicit copies of memory from slow memory to fast memory). IBM's Cell showed that such was "usable" for some workloads with sufficient programming effort. Even if one excluded on-chip memory, could one reasonably exclude having an enormous number of registers? (Such would be even less attractive as a programming target but could still be used. Tera (IIRC) attempted this by hiding latency with threading but the result was not general purpose even for HPC.

Comment: I am not sure what you googled, but 70ns was fast RAM 25 years ago. A quick check on DigiKey yields ram as fast as 0.195ns or 195ps. So faster ram does exist.